# Refreshing the access token from azure ad

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have a scenario where my API updates some claims in active directory via the Graph API.
In such case, I notify the client via response headers that it needs to refresh the access token, in order to get a token with the new claims.

The problem is that when I call `acquireTokenSilent` (in `Msal.UserAgentApplication`) in gives me the old token. I found out that it happens because Msal saves the access token in sessionStorage/localStorage.

Is there a way for me to explicitly request a new access token without directly removing the cache?

Comment: You could use the refresh token to get the new access token. If no refresh token, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc) to get refresh token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`acquireTokenSilent` method will acquire and renew tokens silently in the background. The access token will expired in an hour by default. After 1 hour, you will get a new access token. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#access-tokens).

Usually we can use the refresh token to refresh access token. But in msal.js this is not transparent. Anyway, you can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55602618/10504999).

You can sign out and sign in again. Then you will get a new access token.

You can also call `acquireTokenPopup` or `acquireTokenRedirect` method to acquire a new access token, but they are interactive methods.

Refer to [How to renew tokens with MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs#q3-how-to-renew-tokens-with-msaljs) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use a refresh token as mentioned.